# Can we have multple private Keys with single public key?

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I am encrypting data with public key and decrypting data with private key.

Is there a possibility of having multiple private keys with a single public key?

Comment: The answer depends on what exactly do you consider as “public key” and “private key”. If it's simply `e`/`d` for RSA and `y`/`x` for DSA, then **yes** — provided you vary basic parameters `p`/`q`/`n` for RSA and `p`/`q`/`g` for DSA. If you consider the whole combination of (`n`, `e`) and (`p`, `q`, `g`, `y`) as public keys, then **no**, obviously.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp If it hadn't been asked very recently...

Comment: @owlstead if people read rules before doing something, life would be much easier :)

Comment: I also got a use case for this, did you find any existing algo for this or you have written your own

Answer (score 1):

No you cant that is an essence of Public Private key encryption. Why do u want to have multiple private keys for a single public key? What if u want to sign an encrypted file?
If that would be possible I would be able to send encrypted file to your friends and sign it with my crafted private key?

Comment: In my case i am sending sensible data to my clients for that i am encrypting my data with public key and they will decrypt data using private key.So in this situation i want to give different private keys to the client which has a common public key.

Comment: No you give your clients your public key and you encrypt it with your private key. That how is it working. And then they encrypt something with your public key and only you can decrypt it :)
Or you have all your clients public keys and for each client you encrypt data using their public key and then they decrypt it with they own Private key

Comment: @Sharr can u please more explain ur last comment. can we encrypt our data with private key and then decrypt using known public key ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose in theory it depends on the algorithm.

But with the ones we generally use (RSA, ECC), there is a 1:1 correspondence, so: no.

Not having a 1:1 correspondence seems like a bad thing. After all, you want to know that only a specified person can be the sender/recipient.

If you want group conversations, this is usually done by encrypting the message with a symmetric session key (you'd do that anyway in all likelihood, because public-key-crypto does not scale well for large messages), and then encrypting the session key (separately) for multiple recipients.

Answer (score 0):

Its not feasible to make multiple private keys from one public key. First a key is generated which will be your private key. The public key pair is generated from this private key. Only one public key can be generated from one key. Here is a simple command to generate public key using RSA algorithm

```
rsa -in <yourkeyname(private key)> -pubout -out <publickeyname>
```